# "Brunette" vs. "brown" and "blonde" vs. "yellow"

Tags: meaning, etymology, adjectives, collocation

Why is that we never use these terms interchangeably? I.e. one wouldn't say "I've painted my walls a deep brunette".

Why is it that "brunette" and "blonde" are used exclusively in reference to hair colour yet they just mean "brown" and "yellow"?

Comment: Because the colour yellow is different from blond/blonde? And brunette describes a woman/girl with dark brown hair quite nicely. You also have "raven haired", "auburn" and "red-heads". More choice is more fun!

Comment: *Blonde* is also used for [wood](https://www.google.com/search?q=blonde+wood&oq=blonde+wood&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5307j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=blond+wood)

Comment: Brunette actually can be used to describe any shade of brown **or black**. That wouldn't be a very useful word for color in general; its ridiculously unspecific. But it makes sense when you are talking about hair color in a society with a very large percentage of blondes (eg: Norman England, where these words came from).

Comment: But you might say 'I've painted a beautiful brunette on my wall'!

Answer (score 1):

According to the OED both 'blonde' and 'brunette' are used exclusively in relation to hair colouring, occasionally extending to the complexions of the persons concerned.

The position is, I believe, much the same in French, from which both words emanate. Except that the City of Lille, Nord-Pas-de-Calais region, is home to the famous 'blonde' - a beer of distinction of the Pelforth brewery, now (perhaps sadly) owned by Heineken.

Comment: I was going to mention beer. But it's *blond* beer, and while that is the masculine form of *blonde,* I believe it's a Flemish word. [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=blond&allowed_in_frame=0) is interesting.

Comment: @AndrewLeach The Wiki article on 'Beer in France' is instructive and spells it 'blonde'. This is not surprising since beer is feminine in French - la bière. 'Blond' and 'blonde' are certainly French words used for hair colouring. But I am away from home and without my French dictionaries, so I must look up the etymology.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Does this convince you about the spelling? http://www.morgenrot.co/pelforth.shtml

Comment: @AndrewLeach I don't think it can be of Flemish origin. The OED etymology shows it to exist in the Romance languages, including medieval Latin, though the ultimate origin is unclear. No mention of it in any variety of German.

Comment: Yes, I looked at OED; which is why I mentioned Etymonline.

Comment: @AndrewLeach  Interesting. No one mentions it as having been present in classical Latin, so perhaps Teutonic?  But Pelforth didn't introduce the Blonde until 1914, so I think we can safely assume that it was a French word by that time. I am becoming quite interested in all this as it was apparently made using an English yeast. Historical context is the Entente Cordiale and the start of the First World War.  I am wondering if there is a history of the Pelforth Brewery!

Comment: @AndrewLeach In French, "blond" can either be an adj. or a noun, "brunette" nowadays only a noun. Both words were borrowed by the English from French. As most adjectives of colour in French are of Germanic origin. The English borrowed "brunette" from the French and were the first to use it with its present meaning before it crossed the Channel for a second time. Just added a notice about brunette to [the wiki on fr.se](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/8285/358) on those words that have crossed the Channel to and back.

Comment: Blond can be used in French - like in English - to describe a hair colour but is also associated to describe some type of wood, of bread, etc. I think it's the same as in English, it would only be used as a sort of technical term but not as a replacement of yellow. *Bière blonde* is first recorded in French in 1882. From Wikipedia's article I gather that [*une bière blonde*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer#Colour) is what the English call a "pale lager". http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/ might have more. If you're stuck on French do visit us at http://french.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm intrigued that no-one thinks that *blond* as in Belgian beer is a Flemish word from Germanic roots.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: I did mention it is of Germanic origin (like most adjectives of colour), but it's via French that it came into the English language (Aftermath of 1066...).

Comment: @WS2 and others: [only partially](http://www.beermerchants.com/blond-beer.html)

Comment: @Laure This was once explained to me as follows: There are two schools of beermaking in the world, the British - darker ales, and the German light lager types. All beers follow one or other of these traditions. Lagers have become popular in Britain since the 1960s but serious beer drinkers, and connoisseurs of real ale still prefer bitter. Prior to the introduction of lager (Scandinavian name) the British brewed Pale Ales e.g.IPA (Indian Pale Ale). These were particularly appreciated in the tropics and the Singapore-brewed 'Tiger Beer' tops them all.

Answer (score 1):

It is useful to have words that describe the hair color of a person.  And hair color is not really the same as "brown" and "yellow"-- hair has unique versions of colors.  It would be useful in English to have more terms that describe hair to go with brunette (brown hair).  I suggest these: noirette (black hair), rougette (red hair), jaunette (blonde hair).  All are based on French words of that color.

Comment: We have real English words for hair-color, you know. *Flaxen-haired* and *raven-haired* and even *tow-headed* need pay no royalties to the French. :)

Comment: Pay a visit to any well stocked supermarket that sells [hair dye kits](http://veliop.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/light-brown-hair-dye-color-chart.jpg) and you'll find "brown" is described in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

English derives heavily from French, and in French you have *brun* and *blonds* instead of *marron* and *jaune* (although *jaune* is a very crude translation). Both [brunette](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=brunette&searchmode=none) and [blond](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=blond) derive from French in this regard. Interestingly, we also follow French in other hair color: when someone has red or black hair, like in French, we use the term red or black to describe it. The Wikipedia page, which I cannot link to due to reputation, has a lot of useful information on the subject.